# Fastboot Stuck, but Device Detected

Tags: linux, android, bootloader, adb

I am on Manjaro Linux, running adb/fastboot version 29.0.2-ArchLinux.

I read others, but their problem is device not being detected and no permission (which is not happening to me).

fastboot commands don't seem to work for some reason (it gets stuck and it's impossible to kill), but the device is being detected just fine:

```bsh
$ adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
BH9012CRCU  device

$ adb reboot bootloader
$ fastboot devices
BH9012CRCU  fastboot
$ fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
^C^C^C^C^X^X^X^X^Z^Z^Z^C^C^C^C^C^C #Stuck with no output; can't exit or kill or anything
```

Now, I try another terminal window, without closing the previous one (because it's impossible).

```bsh
$ fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
< waiting for any device > #Stuck here, but can exit
^C
$ #I gain back control
```

I try to stop/kill/terminate the first fastboot process from task manager, but it does not work. Also, when I shut down, it says something like waiting for session 2 to stop. Only way to stop it is to disconnect device USB.

My device is Sony Xperia XZ2 Compact Dual. I have bootloader already unlocked using Windows (because fastboot does not work on Linux). I would like to use fastboot on Linux without having to boot into Windows everytime...

Thank you.

Comment: So this is not really an answer, but I tried plugging my device into a USB hub this time and it worked. It might have something to do with USB 3 drivers? I really don't know how to diagnose this...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (using a USB-C-to-USB-C cable and also Linux). What I found to work best was:

1. Remove cable / keep cable to phone unattached
2. Execute `fastboot ...` command
3. Only when it shows "`> waiting for device", attach the phone
4. The command works as expected (at least for me)

Note that the same was necessary for nearly all subsequent `fastboot` commands (except `fastboot reboot-bootloader`).